# Default text in JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, settext

I am trying to set default text in a JTextArea. I have tried the `.setText` but that doesn't seem to work. Maybe I am coding it wrong?

The code is as follows:

```
package RootOfFunctionX;

    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.FlowLayout;
    import java.awt.Font;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
    import javax.swing.JTextArea;

    public class BisectionIterations extends JFrame
    implements ActionListener {

private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea("This text should display");
private JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
private JButton closeBtn = new JButton("Close");
//Array
Double[] iterationBi = new Double[1000];

public BisectionIterations(Double[] iter) {
    this.iterationBi = iter;
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setSize(500, 400);
    setTitle("Bisection Method Iterations");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(false);

    JPanel middle = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    middle.add(scrollPane);
    textArea.setEditable(false);
    textArea.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 12));
    textArea.setLineWrap(true);
    textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(490, 330));
    add("Center", middle);

    JPanel bottom = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    middle.add(closeBtn);
    closeBtn.addActionListener(this);
    add("South", bottom);
    displayIterations();

    setVisible(true);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == closeBtn) {
        dispose();
    }
}

public void displayIterations() {
    String j = "";
    for (int i = 1; i < 999; i++) {
        if (iterationBi[i] == null) {

        } else {
            j += "Approximation for iteration '" + i + "' = " + iterationBi[i] + "\n";
        }
    }
    textArea.setText(j);
}
```

}

Comment: `JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea("default_text_here");`

Comment: I have tried that and it's not displaying

Comment: Then you've got a but, but you're not showing us the code causing the error. Create and post your [mcve] (please read the link). Before you think that we want to see all your code or small snippets, we don't -- again please read the link.

Comment: Possible issues: you could be shadowing the JTextArea textArea variable, such that you're adding text to a JTextArea, but not the one displayed, but again, your code does not give us nearly enough to go on to figure this out.

Comment: Is your TextArea appearing without the text or its not being displayed?? and i'm not sure if you can do private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea("This text should display");
private JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea); at the instance scope.

Comment: The textArea is being displayed but without any content text.

Comment: Your iterationBi array could be filled with nulls -- but hard to say since we still cannot run or test your code. Test this to see what it holds by using println's in your displayIterations method. If you still need help, again create and post a true [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is setting default text. I've done it as bellow.

```
public class BisectionIterations extends JFrame
implements ActionListener {

private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea("This text should display");
private JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
private JButton closeBtn = new JButton("Close");
//Array
Double[] iterationBi = new Double[1000];

public BisectionIterations(Double[] iter) {
this.iterationBi = iter;
setLayout(new BorderLayout());
setSize(500, 400);
setTitle("Bisection Method Iterations");
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
setLocationRelativeTo(null);
setResizable(false);

JPanel middle = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
middle.add(scrollPane);
textArea.setEditable(false);
textArea.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 12));
textArea.setLineWrap(true);
textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(490, 330));
add("Center", middle);

JPanel bottom = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
middle.add(closeBtn);
closeBtn.addActionListener(this);
add("South", bottom);
displayIterations();

setVisible(true);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
if (e.getSource() == closeBtn) {
    dispose();
}
}

public void displayIterations() {
String j = "";
for (int i = 1; i < 999; i++) {
    if (iterationBi[i] == null) {

    } else {
        j += "Approximation for iteration '" + i + "' = " +iterationBi[i] + "\n";
    }
}
//textArea.setText(j);
}

public static void main(String args[]){
Double s[];
s = new Double[1000];
for(int i=0;i<1000;i++) {
    s[i]=(double)i;
}
BisectionIterations b=new BisectionIterations(s);
}
}
```

Now if I remove comment 
    //textArea.setText(j);
It will overwrite the default text we've set.

It is actually setting default text but you are note able to see that since it is overwritten by Approximation for iteration......